# Adding an UIView programmatically not working (UIView should show an UIWebView and open URL)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

Currently working on two introduction pages (First shows an image, second should show a website) for my iPhone app (like Pocket, for the user a little hands-on after first start). 
Came across Matthew York's `GitHub` project which works perfectly with `images` and `text`.
Additionally I like to show a website as a part of the introduction but I can't get it working. My `programmatically` created `UIWebView` just doesn't show up.

Matthew York's `GitHub` Project:
https://github.com/MatthewYork/iPhone-IntroductionTutorial

Complete code for showing the two introduction pages is shown below.
Please mind that `panelImage` works as expected but not `panelView`.
I see the second page show up but without the `UIWebView`.
I think I add the `subview` to a `view` not visible on the screen therefore I don't see it. Am I right? Can you please have a look at: `[view addSubview:aWebView];` in `method`: `showWebView`

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)showIntro
{
    MYIntroductionPanel *panelImage = [[MYIntroductionPanel alloc] initWithimage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"] description:@"TEST: IMAGE"];

    MYIntroductionPanel *panelView = [[MYIntroductionPanel alloc] initWitView:[self showWebView] description:@"TEST: VIEW"];

    MYIntroductionView *introductionView = [[MYIntroductionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) headerText:@"TESTING" panels:@[panelImage, panelView] languageDirection:MYLanguageDirectionLeftToRight];

    introductionView.BackgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BG_iPad_1024.png"];
    introductionView.delegate = self;
    [introductionView showInView:self.view];
}

- (UIView *)showWebView
{
    UIWebView *aWebView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 290)];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    [aWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
    [view addSubview:aWebView];

    return view;
}
```

**MYIntroductionPanel.m**

```
-(id)initWitView:(UIView *)view description:(NSString *)description{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.Description = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:description];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithimage:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString *)title description:(NSString *)description{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.Image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        self.Image = image;
        self.Title = title;
        self.Description = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:description];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't love all of the author's decisions, but followed his pattern to achieve what you're looking for.

Added the following:

```
// MyIntroductionPanel.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *url;

-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url;

// MyIntroductionPanel.m
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        _url = url;
    }
    return self;
}
```

That was easy.  This was less easy - hacking the layout method to deal with panels with urls.  I didn't try too hard to understand this method, just added what I could to get it working.  My additions are marked with // DANH

```
//  MYIntroductionView.m

-(UIView *)PanelViewForPanel:(MYIntroductionPanel *)panel atXIndex:(CGFloat*)xIndex{

    // snipped original code    

    NSInteger descriptionHeight = panelDescriptionTextView.contentSize.height;
    int contentWrappedScrollViewHeight = 0;
    if ((imageHeight + descriptionHeight + panelTitleLabelFrame.size.height) > maxScrollViewHeight) {
        contentWrappedScrollViewHeight = maxScrollViewHeight;
        imageHeight = contentWrappedScrollViewHeight-descriptionHeight - panelTitleLabelFrame.size.height - 10;
    }
    else if ((imageHeight+descriptionHeight + panelTitleLabelFrame.size.height) <= maxScrollViewHeight){
        contentWrappedScrollViewHeight = imageHeight + panelTitleLabelFrame.size.height + descriptionHeight;
    }

    // DANH
    if (panel.url) {
        contentWrappedScrollViewHeight = 300;
        // you can certainly do a better job than I did here, but just to get going
    }

    panelView.frame = CGRectMake(*xIndex, 0, self.ContentScrollView.frame.size.width, contentWrappedScrollViewHeight);

    //Build image container
    UIImageView *panelImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, self.ContentScrollView.frame.size.width - 10, imageHeight)];
    panelImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    panelImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    panelImageView.image = panel.Image;
    panelImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    panelImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [panelView addSubview:panelImageView];

    // DANH
    // add webview on top if we have a url
    if (panel.url) {
        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.ContentScrollView.frame.size.width, 300)];
        [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:panel.url]];
        [panelView addSubview:webView];
    }

    // snipped original code    

}
```

Now, to call it with example code....

```
// MYViewController.m

MYIntroductionPanel *panel3 = [[MYIntroductionPanel alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

// ...
MYIntroductionView *introductionView = [[MYIntroductionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) headerText:@"MYIntroductionView" panels:@[panel, panel2, panel3] languageDirection:MYLanguageDirectionLeftToRight];
```

Comment: There's a trivial bug in @McClane's posted code with a trivial solution.  Suggesting that he just give up on what he's doing and copy-paste dozens of lines from some other implementation is counterproductive to say the least.

Comment: @AaronGolden, your solution well stated, but is incorrect.  Please review the code the OP is attempting to extend.  You've suggested that the OP sets self.view = view on MYIntroductionPanel.  That class is a subclass of NSObject, and has no view property (not a great choice by the github author, but that's how we found it).  I didn't copy source from "some other implementation". I took the trouble to get the github project the OP hopes to use, understand it, and extend it to meet his requirements.

Comment: please review the code posted in the question.  You're right that there is no view property on the class in the github repository, but @McClane's posted code in the question does assign to a view property in `initWithView:description:`, so he probably extended the class in his project.

Comment: The code posted in the question is mistaken, which is why the OP needed to ask the question.  You were misled by it.

Answer (score 0):

The view to which you are adding your `UIWebView` is never added to the view hierarchy itself.  You appear to be passing the UIWebView's superview to MyIntroductionPanel's `initWithView:description:` method, but that method just ignores its input view and creates a new one with `self.view = [[UIView alloc] init]`.  Try setting `self.view = view` in your initWithView:description: method instead.

Comment: Incorrect.  See https://github.com/MatthewYork/iPhone-IntroductionTutorial/blob/master/IntroductionExample/MYIntroductionPanel.h.  The class you're suggesting to set self.view = view on is a subclass of NSObject.  It has no view property to set.

Comment: @danh, @McClane must have extended the class then.  The code posted in the question sets the view property in `initWithView:description:`.  Clearly @McClane is working with a version of `MyIntroductionPanel` that has a view property.

Comment: Perhaps he extended it or just added a view property (or perhaps his code doesn't compile).  It won't do any good.  Get the github project and see for yourself.  The "panel" class just keeps params for the MyIntroductionView class.  That's where the views are.  It doesn't add panel classes as subviews.  (the way one would suppose from the name.  Given the poor naming, your mistake here is understandable).  Sorry to say, though, your "trivial" solution may be trivial, but it's no solution at all.